# How is the microcontroller on this dev board programmed?

Tags: microcontroller, pcb

I am trying to understand this schematic page 36-41: [Tiva™ C Series TM4C1294 Connected LaunchPad Evaluation Kit](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spmu365b/spmu365b.pdf).

I would like to know what path the serial stream of "code" follows from the usb before arriving to the main mcu on this schematic? And why you would need that extra microcontroller TM4C123GH6PMI?

Comment: It has a *proprietary* jtag emulator on board. So no, you can't know (unless you are a TI employee) the path. And this extra micro is implementing this emulator.

Comment: @EugeneSh. this explains a lot... You say it is a "proprietary jtag" emulator because the "JTAG_ARM_10PIN" pin, which doesn t have a datasheet online?  In that case: How would I have to wire my usb port to the main mcu to be able to program it via JTAG?

Comment: The programming interface is marked "X1" on the board.

Answer (score 2):

This is currently the way boards like this are done.  The front end board is basically a usb to jtag debugger that they provide with the board for you so you dont have to invest in that separately.  It makes a lot of sense for company XYZ to use another XYZ microcontroller as the usb to jtag tool.

Some use a closed proprietary usb protocol, and some open it up.  In this case at least for Linux there is an open source tool lm4flash (before being acquired by ti, the stellaris product line was from luminary micro (I think the part number started with lm4), was acquired retained the stellaris name, then they changed it to tiva c) which I use for these boards.

More recently ti is conforming to an ARM based usb debugger protocol (XDS100/CMSIS-DAP) rather than the luminary micro proprietary one.  (See the msp432 launchpad for example)

The chip itself uses arms swd protocol, same as many other cortex-m core based products from all of the vendors.  so you you could perhaps use any one of these front ends.  for example the stlink front ends on the st based boards (again one debug microcontroller up front to convert usb to jtag, and the eval/target microcontroller it controls) make it easy, to the point of physically breaking the board into its parts, to program any (well so far) cortex-m that supports the arm swd protocol.

Comment: for this board you can look at the lm4flash source code to see what the usb side of the protocol is.